# Is it possible to fit such a large range plot in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation

I am trying to solve the coupled differential equation numerically with Mathematica. But the range of values are large so mathematica cannot give correct plot. Here is the code:

```
a = 4.75388*10^26;
b = 5.424*10^-3;
d = 4.75388*10^20;
{X, Y} = {x, y} /. 
NDSolve[{x'[
z] == -((a/z) (x[z] - b*z^(3/2) E^(-z)) (BesselK[1, z]/BesselK[2, z])), 
y'[z] == ((d/z) (x[z] - b *z^(3/2) E^(-z)) (BesselK[1, z]/
BesselK[2, z]) - (a *z/4) (BesselK[1, z]) y[z]), 
x[0.1] == 1.552*10^-4, y[0.1] == 10^(-9)}, {x, y}, {z,0.1,100}] // 
FullSimplify // First
LogLogPlot[{X[z], Y[z]}, {z, 0.1, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I am getting an Interpolating function whose domain is restricted to only {0.1,0.1}. I think this is the main reason of all the errors

Comment: This may be an obvious question:  What about normalization of solution (to between 0 and 1) and then plotting it?  Does that help?

Comment: When I run your code the first error I get says `NDSolve::ndlim: Range specification z is not of the form {x, xend} or {x, xmin, xmax}.`

Comment: Are we sure the issue is the size of the numbers and not the 5 errors that are given on evaluation?

Comment: When I run the code, `NDSolve` fails to take the first step (integration step); error `NDSolve::ndsz`. If it did succeed, the plot would fail because `X` is not a function, but a replacement `Rule`; hence `X[z]`, while syntactically allowable, is semantically meaningless. If `NDSolve` can be fixed, try `x[z] /. X` as shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Geneal approach to problems like this is to attempt to regularize your DE. Naive approach in this case would be to replace $x$ with $x1=x/a$ and $y$ with $y1=y/d$:

```
a = 4.75388*10^26;
b = 5.424*10^-3;
d = 4.75388*10^20;

{X, Y} = {x1[#]*a &, y1[#]*d &} /. NDSolve[
    {
     x1'[z] == -((BesselK[1, z] (-b E^-z z^(3/2) + a x1[z]))/(
       z BesselK[2, z]))
     , y1'[z] == (BesselK[1, z] (-b E^-z z^(3/2) + a x1[z]))/(
       z BesselK[2, z]) - (a z BesselK[1, z] y1[z])/4 
     , x1[0.1] == 1.552*10^-4/a
     , y1[0.1] == 10^(-9)/d
     }
    , {x1, y1}
    , {z, 0.1, 100}
    ] // First
LogLogPlot[{X[z], Y[z]}, {z, 0.1, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Resulting $y(z)$ does satisfy boundary conditions:

```
In[]:= Y[0.1]

Out[]= 1.*10^-9
```

But it might be not so obvious from picture above.

```
Plot[Y[z], {z, 0.1, 0.1 + 10^-10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

There is also an interval in which $x(z)$ becomes negative that is displayed somewhat misleading on the `LogLogPlot`

Comment: it is a very approach but why not the y[z] initially starting from near the 10^-9 point since it is one of the given boundary conditions to solve this differential equation

Comment: @user105697 edited reply to your concern into my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I think i have to revisit my input equations carefully.

Comment: BTW, a more straightforward way to get the functions `X`, `Y` is to replace `{x1[#]*a &, y1[#]*d &} /. NDSolve[args...] // First` with `NDSolveValue[args...]`.